# Where are user FactBox preferences persisted in AX2012?

Tags: performance, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

**Background**

We're looking to improve the performance of Dynamics AX 2012 by disabling preview panes and factboxes for all users.
However; we don't want to remove useful features; so want to allow users to re-enable those items which they use (i.e. therefore can't disable through the `client performance options` screen).
We could ask users to go through and manually disable/hide these options, but this would be a lot of work for them, would be something they'd be unlikely to do; whereas re-enabling anything they explicitly need would be less effort and more likely to be done.

**Question**

- Where are user preferences concerning FactBoxes and preview panes stored?
- Is there a simple way to update these en-masse (e.g. through SQL, X++, or some other means)?
- If it's not simple to update these, is there any way to report on who has what enabled; i.e. so we can see which users have which options to help identify those we'd need to chase if asking them to disable these options for themselves?

Comment: The values for personalizations are saved in the system table SysLastValue. I just messed with it for a bit and while I can't seem to copy records from one user to another (the system seems to overwrite them), this would be a good place to start.

Comment: While it is correct that fact box personalizations are stored in table `SysLastValue`, I don't think you can change these personalizations without the gui. If you personalize a fact box on a form, you get three new entries in your usage data (provided there haven't been any before): one each for the form, the fact box and one called 'PartSettings' with the form name as its design name (probably the form specific personalizations of the fact box). But it has the isKernel flag and `xSysLastValue:.getValue` does not return a value for it. Maybe you could copy these records from another user?

Comment: This is a great question.

Comment: Thanks guys; syslastvalue... :(.  That table scares me.  Will feed back on here if I make any progress though.

Comment: @JohnLBevan - just curious if you've made any progress?